# Java azure container connect via SAS token

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-java-get-started?tabs=sas-token#authorize-access-and-connect-to-blob-storage to use a generated token to access files within an azure container.

As a dependency I only use: `implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.14.2'`

My code to connect is as follows:

```
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://mycontainername.blob.core.windows.net/subcontainer")
                .sasToken("sv=2020-10-02&st=2024-03-11T13:58:42Z&se=2024-03-12T14:03:42Z&sr=c&sp=racwl&sig=HVoBAVRrDWaEY1KDr0oxUCFXS8R63L%2B7S5X8n457LTA%3D")
                .buildClient();
```

If I use exactly this string like `<endpoint>?<sasToken>` and append `&restype=container&comp=list` in the browser, I get a representation of all elements within this subcontainer.

But in the code I can't get that to work. As soon as I call something like `container.listBlobs().stream().count()`, so anything that would need to really use the connection, I get a `BlobStorageException`:

```
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:f8b4f3b8-001e-0042-154c-74c44a000000
Time:2024-03-12T07:13:39.0826318Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was racwl
2024-03-11T13:58:42Z
2024-03-12T14:03:42Z
/blob/mycontainername/subcontainer



2020-10-02
c





</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>"
```

The error detail looks quite confusing, is there some encoding/decoding issue maybe?

As I read from the token, the permissions should not be a problem, because `sr=c` (resource=container), `sp=racwl` (permissions=read, access, create, write, list), right?

Comment: Check the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Status code 403: "`AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly, including the signature.

The above error occurs when you don't have proper permission to access the storage account or are passing the wrong SAS token.

In your code, you are missing **`?`** in the SAS token.

Here is the corrected code to get the blob count.

**Code:**

```java
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClientBuilder;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/test")
                .sasToken("?sp=racwl&st=2024-03-12T07:39:44Z&se=2024-03-12T15:39:44Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=Oxxxxx")
                .buildClient();
        long blobCount = containerClient.listBlobs().stream().count();
        System.out.println(blobCount); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11
```

[image: Corrected image]

Comment: Oh yess! Thank you. That was the only error. Wasted 3 hours for this :D
I was somehow thinking the BlobContainerBuilder implementation would add the `?` for me. And I couldn't find out how to get the url the BlobContainerClient is using.

Comment: Great, it worked for you.